# Apache If condition - HTTP Header Param

Tags: apache, if-statement, http-headers, vhosts

I have a question about an  condition into vhost rules.
I need to add and IncludeOptional redirects files only if a specific param into the header is present.

I think that I can do something like:

```
<If "%{HTTP:X-block-redirect} in { 'false' }">
 IncludeOptional ...
</If>
```

but I still think that i'm missing something.
For example, If the block-redirect is not present (or it's false like my If condition), it should add the IncludeOptional files but if it's true it shouldn't.

I think that a condition that match something like:

```
<If "%{HTTP:X-block-redirect} **not** in { 'true' }"> 
...
</If>
```

can work better but I'm struggling on how to create an if like *"if NOT this DO that"*...
Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve this I've just used a single (and simple) !='true' condition.

```
<If "%{HTTP:X-value} !='true'">
 IncludeOptional ...
</If>
```

I thought I could not check a single value instead of an array of values, but I was wrong.

I hope this solution can help someone else with similar problems!